# Capslock LED does not turn on

Tags: keyboard, raspbian, capslock

I have a raspberry with raspbian-lite and the problem is that the capslock led does not work when the keyboard is connected to it. The problem is not with the keyboard, as it works on other computers.

I tried doing

```
ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, KDSETLED, 7);
```

which supposedly turns on every led, but the capslock didn't (the others yes).

But if I write `1` instead of `0` directly to the file that contains the brightness info of the capslock led (located somewhere at `/sys`) then it turns on.

Why does not the led work without writing directly to the file?

I also noticed that the event file of the usb interface which contains the leds (in `/dev`) does not work as expected. I tried in other computers to read the equivalent file, and when I press capslock or numlock some data appears. In the file in the raspberry when I do the same thing data does not appear.